# Laravel Vite Deployment to Host

Tags: php, laravel, vite

I'm having a trouble with Vite in Laravel. I ran the command **npm run build** and then I uploaded files to my shared hosting. But it doesn't load css and js files.

I've put `@vite(['resources/css/admin.css', 'resources/js/app.js'])` at the top of the script.
Then I ran the command `npm run build`.
And then uploaded all files to my shared hosting.
I tried to open the page. Style and JS files looks like this on page source;

```html
<script type="module" src="http://127.0.0.1:5173/@vite/client"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://127.0.0.1:5173/resources/css/admin.css" />
<script type="module" src="http://127.0.0.1:5173/resources/js/app.js"></script>
```

And it gives me these errors in browser console obviously because it tries to get files from localhost.

[image: Vite browser console errors]

Which configurations should I make in Vite?

Comment: Laravel shouldn't be trying to get assets from your local machine when it's in production. You've got something misconfigured somewhere, you've either hardcoded a local address or you've got a config file somewhere which is pointing to a local address.

Comment: Please edit your question to contain properly formatted text, not images of text. See [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) for many reasons why this is important. Also: there's really no specific programming question here.

Comment: I edited the question. The image is Chrome console errors. Nothing more. Problem is not that. Problem is; Vite tries to get files from localhost. Why? Where am I missing?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I found the solution. The problem was the **hot** file in public. It will be fixed when you delete `public/hot` file. Do not forget to run **npm run build** command before you upload your files.

Comment: Just deleting the hot file in the public solved my issue ,thanks man

Comment: ohh man, I wasted an hour trying to figure it out. Never seen this before. Much appreciated

Comment: There is no hot file inside public folder. It is not working for me. Can you help? I have done the npm run build also

Answer (score -2):

that's a silly problem, you are sending the requests to the http://127.0.0.1 not the host! you have to send the request to for expample https://hostname.com not  http://127.0.0.1

Comment: I do not specify the host address. Vite does all the thing. I just write **@vite(['resource/app.css'])**. And the problem was with the **hot** file in public. If the hot file exists in public folder, app thinks it's in development mode. I deleted that file and it fixed.

Comment: @Blitzconn Thank you so much! I literally spent over an hour for this